# The screen in navigationlink cannot be set to disabled

Tags: swift, swiftui-navigationlink

I have two pages that were wrapped by ZStack, and I have set the disabled attribute on ZStack. But this does not apply to the page placed in the navigation link, it only applies to another page.

```
NavigationView {
  ZStack {
    if condition1 { 
      Navigationlink(destination:page1,isActive :$isactive)
    } else if condition2 {
        page2
    }
  }.disabled(true)
}
```

I have tried placing the disabled attribute outside the Navigationview instead of the ZStack, which is useful, but it can cause other problems. Deleting the Navigationlink can also cause other problems. Is there any other solution？

Comment: Hmm, so what is the question? Do you want if `condition1` then `Navigationlink` can't be tappable?

Comment: Note, `NavigationView` is deprecated you should use `NavigationStack`.
 Also there is no `Navigationlink(destination:page1,isActive :$isactive)`
 it should be `NavigationLink("xxxx", destination: page1, isActive: $isactive)`.
 After fixing those the `NavigationLink` is **disabled** in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code with the following code example

```
NavigationView {
      ZStack {
        if condition1 {
            NavigationLink("Page 1", destination: EmptyView())
        } else if condition2 {
            Text("Page 2")
        }
      }.disabled(true)
    }
```

[image]